# Detectar touch durante una animación en Swift

Tags: swift

Tengo una clase Canvas que hereda de UIView la cual estoy utilizando para crear un objeto en el que dibujar. Quiero que cuando el usuario deje de tocar la pantalla el objeto canvas haga una animación de fadeOut que convierta su alpha a 0.1 pero en el momento en el que el usuario vuelva a poner el dedo sobre la pantalla se haga una animación inversa para mostrar de nuevo el dibujo con un alpha 1.0. El fadeOut lo hago así:

```
func fadeOut(time:TimeInterval){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: time, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0.1
    })
}
```

El problema es que hasta que no termina de ejecutarse la animación del alpha no vuelven a detectarse los eventos de touch. Y aunque intento parar la animación el código no se ejecuta.

```
func fadeIn(time: TimeInterval){
    self.alpha = 1.0
    self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de volver a detectar los touch durante la animación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con el otro método que las animaciones de `UIView` que te permite seleccionar opciones para la animación:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: time,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: [ .allowUserInteraction, .beginFromCurrentState ]
                   animations: {
        self.alpha = 0.1
    }, completion: nil)
```